# correlate in TensorFlow (like numpy.correlate)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Is there a CORRELATE function in TensorFlow (like `numpy.correlate`)? For example,

```
numpy.correlate(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/stats/correlation) doc. But I don't work with this framework.

I installed it using `pip install --upgrade tensorflow-probability`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp


x = tf.random_uniform((5,2),2,3)
y = tf.random_uniform((5,2),2,3)


corr = tfp.stats.correlation(x, y)

with tf.Session() as sess :
    print(sess.run( corr))
```

> [[ 0.32789752 -0.12169117]
>
> [ 0.83670807 -0.09973542]]